# Is gradle sync important for every new project

Tags: android

I am new to app development with android studio.

When I started android studio IDE for my first project I had my data connected and due to poor network here it took time for gradle sync to complete.

Now I want to practice another project. After create an empty activity, gradle sync begins again and at the button right of the project window, I could see some files libraries and other files been downloaded.

Please master in this, does this means I must get connected each time I want to create a new project and allow the files to be downloaded or there's a way about it?

Thanks

I tried different search queries from goigke when I got the error "Cannot resolve class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'" when I decide to turn off data connection but didn't help so I had to start all over with my internet connection.

Comment: the internet connection is required to download dependencies that are written in your build.gradle files when dependency has been downloaded it's stored in gradle cache so next time when some of your projects will require that dependency it will be taken from the cache so the internet connection isn't required here, but it works only if the required dependency has exact the same version like in the cache, otherwise it will be downloaded from internet